# How to list the regions in an HBase table through the shell?

Tags: hbase

I would like to get the same information about the regions of a table that appear in the web UI (i.e. region name, region server, start/end key, locality), but through the hbase shell.

(The UI is flaky/slow, and furthermore I want to process this information as part of a script.)

After much googling, I can't find out how, and this surprises me immensely.  version is 1.0.0.-cdh5.4.0

Comment: Turns out you can't (yet).  There's an open ticket https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-14925 to add it.

Comment: FYI, one of the major reasons I wanted this was that the UI wouldn't always show the table regions.  I found out through luck that if you do a major_compact on the table, somehow this refreshes the table metadata in a way that causes the UI to show the table regions.  So at least I can get the info now.  But still would be super nice to be able to use this info in a script in an easy way that didn't use screen scraping!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

To get the region info about the table, you need to scan `hbase:meta` table.

```
scan 'hbase:meta',{FILTER=>"PrefixFilter('table_name')"}
```

This command will give details of all the regions. Row key will have region name and there will be four column qualifiers. You may need following two column qualifiers:

`info:regioninfo` - This qualifier contains STARTKEY and ENDKEY.

`info:server` - This qualifier contains region server details

Comment: Now there is an official command for it, check out https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-14925
Starting from version 1.4

Answer (score 10):

Use the "official" `list_regions` shell command to list out all the regions. Note that this tool is available only starting from HBase versions 1.4 and above.

```
Some examples are 
        Examples:
        hbase> list_regions 'table_name'
        hbase> list_regions 'table_name', 'server_name'
        hbase> list_regions 'table_name', {SERVER_NAME => 'server_name', LOCALITY_THRESHOLD => 0.8}
        hbase> list_regions 'table_name', {SERVER_NAME => 'server_name', LOCALITY_THRESHOLD => 0.8}, ['SERVER_NAME']
        hbase> list_regions 'table_name', {}, ['SERVER_NAME', 'start_key']
        hbase> list_regions 'table_name', '', ['SERVER_NAME', 'start_key']
```

Details on its implementation are at: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-14925

Answer (score 5):

```
scan 'hbase:meta', {FILTER=>"PrefixFilter('tableName')", COLUMNS=>['info:regioninfo']}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a response from the HBase mailing list:

status 'detailed' would show you enough information 
e.g.

```
t1,30,1449175546660.da5f3853f6e59d1ada0a8554f12885ab." 
  numberOfStores=1, numberOfStorefiles=0, 
  storefileUncompressedSizeMB=0, lastMajorCompactionTimestamp=0, 
  storefileSizeMB=0, memstoreSizeMB=0, storefileIndexSizeMB=0, 
  readRequestsCount=0, writeRequestsCount=0, rootIndexSizeKB=0, 
  totalStaticIndexSizeKB=0, totalStaticBloomSizeKB=0, totalCompactingKVs=0, 
  currentCompactedKVs=0, compactionProgressPct=NaN, completeSequenceId=-1, 
  dataLocality=0.0
```

However, this returns info from *all* the tables, and you need to parse the regions of the table you're interested in.

Answer (score 3):

There is a tool in hbase which is used for table recovery and checking consistency, called *hbase hbck*. Although this will not be running inside the hbase shell, but can be used to get the list of regions.

The command `hbase hbck -details <tablename>` can be used to get the table details and will contain the region information required.

The output of the above-mentioned command can be parsed to obtain the region-info for the required table.